# Java - Easier way to account for all scenarios of user input

Tags: java

I'm working on a program that creates a 4th edition DnD character based on user inputed values and I would like to know if there is an easier way to proceed with what I am doing before I continue as I am. The current part of the program I am working on is having the user assign pre-selected values to their skills. My code for testing this part is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testCodeThree{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        standardArray(scan);
    }


    public static void standardArray(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Assign the numbers \"16\", \"14\", \"13\", \"12\", \"11\", and \"10\" to your skills.");

        System.out.print("Enter your desired Str stat: ");
        int userStr = scan.nextInt();

        int strMod = 0;
        int conMod = 0;
        int dexMod = 0;
        int intMod = 0;
        int wisMod = 0;
        int chaMod = 0;

        if (userStr == 16 || userStr == 14 || userStr == 13 || userStr == 12 || userStr == 11 || userStr == 10) {
            switch (userStr) {
            case 16: // 16 Str, -- Con, -- Dex, -- Int, -- Wis, -- Cha
                strMod = 3;
                System.out.print("Enter your desired Con stat: ");
                int userCon = scan.nextInt();

                if (userCon == 14 || userCon == 13 || userCon == 12 || userCon == 11 || userCon == 10) {
                    switch (userCon) {
                    case 14: // 16 Str, 14 Con, -- Dex, -- Int, -- Wis, -- Cha
                        conMod = 2;
                        System.out.print("Enter your desired Dex stat: ");
                        int userDex = scan.nextInt();

                        if (userDex == 13 || userDex == 12 || userDex == 11 || userDex == 10) {
                            switch (userDex) {
                            case 13: // 16 Str, 14 Con, 13 Dex, -- Int, -- Wis, -- Cha
                                dexMod = 1;
                                System.out.print("Enter your desired Int stat: ");
                                int userInt = scan.nextInt();

                                if (userInt == 12 || userInt == 11 || userInt == 10) {
                                    switch (userInt) {
                                    case 12: // 16 Str, 14 Con, 13 Dex, 12 Int, -- Wis, -- Cha
                                        intMod = 1;
                                        System.out.print("Enter your desired Wis stat: ");
                                        int userWis = scan.nextInt();

                                        if (userWis == 11 || userWis == 10) {
                                            switch (userWis) {
                                            case 11: // 16 Str, 14 Con, 13 Dex, 12 Int, 11 Wis, 10 Cha
                                                int userCha = 10;
                                                System.out.println("Your Charisma stat is "+ userCha);
                                                break;

                                            default: // 16 Str, 14 Con, 13 Dex, 12 Int, 10 Wis, 11 Cha
                                                userCha = 11;
                                                System.out.println("Your Charisma stat is "+ userCha);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
                                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                                        standardArray(scan);
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case 11:
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                                standardArray(scan);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 12:
                            dexMod = 1;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            // dexMod does not get updated here because the
                            // modifier is zero.
                            break;
                        default:
                            // dexMod does not get updated here because the
                            // modifier is zero.
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                        standardArray(scan);
                    }
                    break;
                case 13:
                    conMod = 1;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    conMod = 1;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    // conMod does not get updated here because the modifier
                    // is zero.
                    break;
                default:
                    // conMod does not get updated here because the modifier
                    // is zero.
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                standardArray(scan);
            }
            break;
        case 14:
            strMod = 2;
            break;
        case 13:
            strMod = 1;
            break;
        case 12:
            strMod = 1;
            break;
        case 11:
            // strMod does not get updated here because the modifier is
            // zero.
            break;
        default:
            // strMod does not get updated here because the modifier is
            // zero.
            break;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
        standardArray(scan);
    }
}
```

}

My initial idea was to ask to the user to input what number they want for their Str stat and then use nested if statements/switch statements to determine what they inputed for the following stats. The reason I don't want to do this is because I would have to account for every possible order of the numbers being inputed (16,14,13,12,11,10 or 16,13,14,11,10,12 etc...), coming to a total of a lot of if and case statements. Is there a way to do this that requires less lines?

EDIT: The user cannot enter the same number for more than one skill.

Feel free to ask questions if you have some.

Comment: Whoa... this is a mess...

Comment: So... when we're entering the 3rd number, why does it matter what order the first two were entered?  It appears that, as far as the third number is concerned, it only matters whether or not the user is attempting to enter a valid input, right?

Comment: For example, for the first number, the valid inputs are 10-16.  But for the third number, the valid inputs might be 10-14, regardless of the order the first two numbers entered, right (assuming 16/15 are entered first/second, in any order)?

Comment: For the second number the valid inputs would be 10-14, assuming 16 was entered for the first number. I forgot the mention in the post the user cannot enter the same number for more than one skill (edited to say that now).

Comment: Why is `15` an invalid entry as the second number if it wasn't picked for the first number?

Comment: Doesn't the rule set specify a mathematical function for this kind of thing?

Comment: 15 is not a value that can be entered. Only 16, 14, 13, 12, 11 or 10 can be entered.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see.  But assuming 16/14 are entered as the first two numbers, the user can enter 10-13 for the third number, irregardless of the order the first two were entered, correct?

Comment: Yes they can enter 10-13 for the third number if 14 and 16 are already gone.

Comment: So, to the point, it DOESN'T actually matter what order the numbers are entered.  It matters that the first number is assigned to `strMod` and is marked as unavailable for use.  It matters that the second number is assigned to `conMod` and is marked as unavailable for future use.  But the point is, for each task of taking use input, all you have to do is keep track of what numbers are still valid, and assign a valid value to the current mod you're working on.  This doesn't explicitly help you, but should give you a way of thinking about the problem which should result in more concise code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many ways to do that.

This is one way, using a Set to see if the values are unique, and using functions to avoid repeating much code.

```
private static boolean isValidStat(int userStat) {
    return userStat >= 10 && userStat <= 16 && userStat != 15;
}

private static int readStat(Scanner scan, String stat, Set<Integer> seenStats) {
    System.out.println("Enter your desired "+stat+" stat: ");
    while(true) {
        int userStat = scan.nextInt();
        if(!isValidStat(userStat))
            System.out.println("Not a valid choice - please try again:");
        else if(seenStats.contains(userStat))
            System.out.println("Already used that number - please try again:");
        else {
            seenStats.add(userStat);
            return userStat;
        }
    }
}

private static int getMod(int userStat) {
    switch(userStat) {
    case 16: return 3;
    case 14: return 2;
    case 13: return 1;
    case 12: return 1;
    case 11: return 0;
    case 10: return 0;
    default: throw new RuntimeException("invalid userStat "+userStat); // shouldn't happen
    }
}

public static void standardArray(Scanner scan) {

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Assign the numbers \"16\", \"14\", \"13\", \"12\", \"11\", and \"10\" to your skills.");
    Set<Integer> seenStats = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int userStr = readStat(scan, "Str", seenStats);
    int userCon = readStat(scan, "Con", seenStats);
    int userDex = readStat(scan, "Dex", seenStats);
    int userInt = readStat(scan, "Int", seenStats);
    int userWis = readStat(scan, "Wis", seenStats);
    int userCha = readStat(scan, "Cha", seenStats);

    int strMod = getMod(userStr);
    int conMod = getMod(userCon);
    int dexMod = getMod(userDex);
    int intMod = getMod(userInt);
    int wisMod = getMod(userWis);
    int chaMod = getMod(userCha);

    /* do something with all these numbers, of course */
}
```

Comment: At my level, I haven't learned about sets at all but I thank you for introducing me to something new while I go do some googling.

Comment: Short version: a set is like a list but it will stop you adding the same thing twice. Also "contains" is efficient. You could replace Set with List and it would still work, it would just be more ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use comparison operators for one thing, ie:

```
if(userStr <= 16 && userStr >= 10) {
```

instead of

```
if(userStr == 16 || userStr == 14 || userStr == 13 || userStr == 12 || userStr == 11 || userStr == 10)
```

Comment: While this is a valid point, in comes no where near addressing the actual question.

Comment: This doesn't reduce the lines of code either.  It takes a single line and makes it narrower.  (Moreover, 15 is apparently not a valid entry..)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this could be much more organized by using an array for the input:

```
int[] stats = new int[6];

int current = 0;

for (;;) {
    System.out.print("Enter your desired Str stat: ");
    stats[current] = scan.nextInt();
```

Then you can validate them against each other in loops:

```
    if (dndValidStarterStats(stats, current)) {
        break;

    } else {
        System.out.println(
            "Stats must be 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, or 16 and unique."
        );
    }
}

for (current++; ;) {
    System.out.print("Enter your desired Con stat: ");
    stats[current] = scan.nextInt();

    ...
}

public static boolean dndValidStarterStats(int[] stats, int current) {
    if ( stats[current] > 16 ||
         stats[current] == 15 ||
         stats[current] < 10 ) {

        return false;
    }

    /* specifically you get to do this */
    for (int eval = 0; eval < current; eval++) {
        if (stats[eval] == stats[current]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You could shorten the entry logic in to a single loop if you created a basic data structure for this:

```
public class Stat {
    public final String name;
    public int val = 0;

    private Stat(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static final int STR = 0;
    public static final int CON = 1;
    public static final int DEX = 2;
    public static final int INT = 3;
    public static final int WIS = 4;
    public static final int CHA = 5;

    public static List<Stat> createStats() {
        Stat[] stats = new Stat[6];
        stats[STR] = new Stat("Strength");
        stats[CON] = new Stat("Constitution");
        stats[DEX] = new Stat("Dexterity");
        stats[INT] = new Stat("Intelligence");
        stats[WIS] = new Stat("Wisdom");
        stats[CHA] = new Stat("Charisma");

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(stats));
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
List<Stat> stats = Stat.createStats();

Stat entry;
for (int current = 0; current < stats.size();) {
    entry = stats.get(current);

    System.out.print(
        "Enter your desired " + stats.get(current).name + " stat: "
    );

    stats[current].val = scan.nextInt();

    if (dndValidStarterStats(stats, current)) {
        current++;

    } else {
        System.out.println(
            "Stats must be 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, or 16 and unique."
        );
    }
}
```

Defining a constant for each index lets you access them from the array in map-like O(1) as in `stats.get(Stat.STR).val++;`. I don't really see a reason to involve an existing Map because you know exactly what's going in it ahead of time, there's only 6 elements and you don't need to modify them after creation.